# Find the the path connecting 2 points on a skeleton

Tags: python, opencv

I'm looking for a way to find a path that connecting 2 points on a skeleton
given that I already have a skeletonize image and 2 points on the skeleton
[Skeletonize image and 2 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yullr.png)

this is for my python project

The result should be something like this
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyby0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).